# Adding User in LDAP

Tags: java, hibernate, api, spring-mvc, ldap

I'm able to create the user in LDAP but its creating in disabled mode. When try to enable and give the password as Never Expire got this error. LDAP: error code 53 - 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A11E5, problem 5003

Answer (score 0):

This error code is very specific to Active Directory and indicates an "Unwilling to Perform". You can only set a password if the connection is secured by a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The hex value `0000052D` of your diagnostic message relates to a system error code. Specifically:

> ERROR_PASSWORD_RESTRICTION
>
> ```
> 1325 (0x52D)
>
> Unable to update the password. The value provided for the new password
> does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirements of the domain.
> ```

Either the password you are trying to set for the user account does not meet the password policy requirements or you are not encoding it properly (unicodePwd must be UTF-16LE).